# which of the following can be expressed by exact length but not by exact number?

Tags: number-theory

which of the following can be expressed by  exact length but not by  exact number?

(i) $ \sqrt{10}  $

(ii) $ \sqrt{7} $

(iii) $ \sqrt{13} \ $

(iv) $ \ \sqrt{11} \ $

**Answer:**

I basically could not understand th question.

What is meant by expressing by exact length ?

**Does we need to satisfy Pythagorean law?**

Help me with hints

Comment: Can you provide more contest? All these number are constructible, so where does the question come from?

Comment: Constructable means?

Comment: That you can draw a line with their length exactly.

Comment: now which can not be expressed by exact number?

Comment: None of them can. They're all irrational and so the number goes on forever, and has no cycle.

Comment: How can you express $ \sqrt 7 \ $  so that it satisfy pythagorean law?

Comment: Constructable numbers are not necessarily build using the pythagorean law. You can easily provide a short construction using Euclid's theorems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "cannot be expressed by exact number" means they are irrational so the decimal does not terminate, which is true of all of them.

I think "can be expressed by exact length" means you can construct it.  You are expected to notice that $10=3^2+1^2$ so you can draw a segment of length $1$, a perpendicular segment of length $3$, make the hypotenuse, and that will be a segment of length $\sqrt{10}$.  Similarly $13=3^2+2^2$ so it is easy to construct.

$\sqrt 7$ is constructible as well, but not in such a simple way.  You can construct $\sqrt 5=\sqrt {2^2+1^2}$, then $\sqrt 6=\sqrt{\sqrt{5}^2+1^2}$ and finally $\sqrt 7$.  From $\sqrt 7$ (or in other ways) you can construct $\sqrt {11}$.

Answer (score 4):

The [spiral of Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus)  constructs the square roots of the positive integers.

[image]

Comment: Ethan.Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong .

$√n$ is constructible, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

$n=1$, ok.

Assume $√n$ is constructible.

Step:

Show that $\sqrt{n+1}$ is constructible.

Pythagorean Theorem:

$(\sqrt{n})^2+1= n+1= (\sqrt{n+1})^2$, i.e.

construct a right triangle with leg lengths, $1$ and $√n$,

then the length of the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{n+1}$.